# How can I disable the inline implementation window that pops up when I use "Create definition of function" in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

Call me a dinosaur but I'm not very much a fan of this inline window that pops up in Visual Studio when I right click on a function declaration classes `.h` file to use "Quick Actions and Refactorings -> Create definition of 'function' in 'ClassName.cpp'":

[image: Annoying Visual Studio behavior]

Is there any way I can disable this behavior? This is very distracting for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Tools → Options → Text Editor → C/C++ → Advanced and scroll down to refactoring and change the setting "Navigation after Create Declaration/Definition" from Peek Document to either None or Open Document.

[image]